# Really strange numpy array floating point behavior

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point

I am working with numpy for the first time and am experiencing some very strange issues with floating-point arrays.

This is extremely basic and I am probably missing something very obvious here -- can anyone tell me what the problem is?

These two lines of code

```
arr1 = numpy.ndarray([1.0, 2.0])
print "arr1: ", arr1
```

produce this output:

```
arr1:  [[  1.49166815e-154  -1.32750723e-315]]
```

That's... not right. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `numpy.array` to create an array not `numpy.ndarray`. `numpy.ndarray` is a low-level interface, and in most cases `numpy.array` should be used to create an array.

```
In [5]: arr1 = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0])                                                            

In [6]: arr1
Out[6]: array([ 1.,  2.])
```

Signature of `numpy.ndarray`:

```
ndarray(shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0, strides=None, order=None)
```

So, the first argument is `shape` not the array. So, numpy filled your array with some random data.

From the [docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) of `numpy.ndarray`:

> Arrays should be constructed using `array`, `zeros` or `empty`.

Answer (score 2):

The argument that you are specifying is the shape. To fill with data you need to specify the buffer argument.

```
np.ndarray(shape=(1,2), buffer=np.array([1,2]), dtype=float)
```